# get previous value of record that's updated in sql server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have database with many table 
The SQL Server records every transaction, either it is Start or End. It saves every activity performed in a database(insert, update, or delete)

You can read the contents of log file using undocumented command
`SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)`
this function returns 63 records
to get every thing occurs on database.

if i made any update of any record in any table

i need to know the last value in this record and the current value.

can i do this?

Comment: The format of the log is undocumented and it would be a decidedly non trivial amount of work to write a log parser with the number of features and storage formats in SQL Server (not to mention that because it is undocumented it can change at any time) so you're better off doing whatever you need some other way.

Comment: If you want to keep history, add a `active` column and when new values come, update closed one to the current one, and the open one to the new one values.

Comment: I would recommend keeping a history table instead of doing soft deletes and cluttering up a busy table with historical values.